Power spectrum: $uV^2$ scale
I was reading a paper and found this figure:

The paper defines slow wave activity as the mean power in the slow wave frequency band (0.4 to 5 Hz). I'm used to seeing power measured in "raw power" (i.e. the direct result of the FFT) or in dB. Here, however, it's expressed in $uV^2$. What is this scale?

Most likely it's supposed to be $\mu V^2$ which is a squared voltage., i.e. $(1mV)^2 = 1 \mu V^2$. This is a quantity related to power. To get actual physical power you would have assume an impedance which can be difficult. Adding a link to the paper would help here.

I added a hyperlink in the word "paper". Thank you. The quantity is "related to power", but how can one transform the power spectrum of a signal to $\mu V^2$?

@lafinur Power is voltage squared divided by resistance (impedance), so that is why power is linearly related to voltage squared.

@Justme: that's only true if the impedance is real.
